# Why cant my javascript work for all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

Hi currently I wrote this java script to be able to display and hide contents from the selected tabs. But when i tried creating another UL tag, my script only apply to my first UL tag but not the second. Anybody can help me? the following is my java script.

```
var tabLinks = new Array();
var contentDivs = new Array();

function init() {

  // Assign onclick events to the tab links, and
  // highlight the first tab
  var i = 0;

  for ( var id in tabLinks ) {
    tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
    tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() { this.blur() };
    if ( i == 0 ) tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
    i++;
  }

  // Hide all content divs except the first
  var i = 0;

  for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
    if ( i != 0 ) contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
    i++;
  }
}

function showTab() {
  var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );

  // Highlight the selected tab, and dim all others.
  // Also show the selected content div, and hide all others.
  for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
    if ( id == selectedId ) {
      tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
      contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent';
    } else {
      tabLinks[id].className = '';
      contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
    }
  }

  // Stop the browser following the link
  return false;
}

function getFirstChildWithTagName( element, tagName ) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
    if ( element.childNodes[i].nodeName == tagName ) return element.childNodes[i];
  }
}

function getHash( url ) {
  var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' );
  return url.substring( hashPos + 1 );
}
```

Comment: At a guess, don't use `getFirstChildWithTagName`.

Comment: Tip: Don't use `for..in` to loop arrays, use regular `for` loops. Maybe you want an object?

Comment: Do you know how to use console? If you don't: right click, "inspect element," then click to the console tab for js error messages. At least that's it in chrome, should be similar in other browsers.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch What can I use other than getFirstChildWithTagName?

Comment: @elclanrs I use for..in to get the properties of the object

Comment: @JamesG. I know. but there is not error in my script just that it doesnt want to applied it to my second UL tag.

Comment: Are you trying to create the second UL tag dynamically within javascript? If so, then init() method have to be called when you create the new UL.
Still it will not work, because new UL and  corresponding li has the same id like the previous UL. But ids have to be unique in a whole document. That's why when you will try to invoke init() method, it will only work on the first UL with the same id. 
I don't know how appropriate this answer is, why don't you start a jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: @user2975123 Oh I get what you mean. Because both my UL tag has the same ID of "Tag" it wont work because ID are unique unless I change it to class. Alright thanks! will give it a try. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you want to use an [Element Selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) like so

```
$( "ul" ) // <-- what you do with it, I can't say - I'd need to 
          //     see more of your code.
```